# How to edit programmatically a row of a sharepoint List without Event receiver

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

please i need your help, i want to edit programmatically a SharePoint 2013 List.
I get some Datalist from a Service and i need to edit some special field in Sharepoint list. i don't know how to do it. Please has somebody an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will be more specific regarding your problem.

As per my understanding you can edit the item using [Server Side Object Model](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/how-to-createupdatedelete-sharepoint-2010-list-items-using-client-object-model/) or [Client Side Object model](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/399156/SharePoint-Client-Object-Model-Introduction) or you can do it using REST API